# Programmatically generating symbol macros

Tags: common-lisp

I've got a data structure that consists of two parts:

1. A hash table mapping symbols to indices
2. A vector of vectors containing data

For example:

```
(defparameter *h* (make-hash-table))
(setf (gethash 'a *h*) 0)
(setf (gethash 'b *h*) 1)
(setf (gethash 'c *h*) 2)

(defparameter *v-of-v* #(#(1 2 3 4)       ;vector a
                         #(5 6 7 8)       ;vector b
                         #(9 10 11 12)))  ;vector c
```

I'd like to define a symbol macro to get at vector `a` without going through the hashmap. At the REPL:

```
(define-symbol-macro a (aref *v-of-v* 0))
```

works fine:

```
* a
#(1 2 3 4)
```

but there could be potentially many named vectors, and I don't know what the mappings will be ahead of time, so I need to automate this process:

```
(defun do-all-names ()
  (maphash #'(lambda (key index)
           (define-symbol-macro key (aref *v-of-v* index)))
       *h*))
```

But that does nothing.  And neither does any of the combinations I have tried of making do-all-names a macro, back-quote/comma templates, etc. I am beginning to wonder if this doesn't have something to do with the `define-symbol-macro` itself.  It seems a little used feature, and On Lisp only mentions it twice. Not too many mentions here nor elsewhere either. In this case I'm using SBCL 2.1

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why wouldn't you directly want to `(setf (gethash 'a *h*) #(1 2 3 4))`?

Comment: Because the vector may change during the course of a session and 'a' needs to always return the latest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like above to do it at runtime:

```
(defun do-all-names ()
  (maphash #'(lambda (key index)
               (eval `(define-symbol-macro ,key (aref *v-of-v* ,index)))
           *h*))
```

`DEFINE-SYMBOL-MACRO` is a macro and does not evaluate all its arguments. So you need to generate a new macro form for each argument pair and evaluate it.

The other way to do it, usually at compile time, is to write a macro which generates these forms on the toplevel:

```
(progn
  (define-symbol-macro a (aref *v-of-v* 0))
  (define-symbol-macro b (aref *v-of-v* 1))
  ; ....
  )
```

Comment: That should have been 'obvious', but wasn't. I don't think I can remember ever having to use 'eval' as a requirement before. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder why they left out the obvious `symbol-macro-function` in the spec?  Perhaps because symbol macros were (if I recall correctly) very late, but also perhaps because it's not obvious at all that such a thing should exist, for some reason I've not thought of...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure on what you mean by "I don't know what the mappings will be ahead of time".

You could do something like:

```lisp
(macrolet ((define-accessors ()
             `(progn
                ,@(loop for key being the hash-keys of *h*
                        collect
                        `(define-symbol-macro ,key (aref *v-of-v* ,(gethash key *h*)))))))
  (define-accessors))
```

If you know you do not require global access, then, you could do:

```lisp
(defmacro with-named-vector-accessors (&body body) ; is that the name you want?
  `(symbol-macrolet (,@(loop for key being the hash-keys of *h*
                             collect `(,key (aref *v-of-v* ,(gethash key *h*)))))
     ,@body))

;;; Example Usage:
(with-named-vector-accessors
  (list a b c)) ;=> (#(1 2 3 4) #(5 6 7 8) #(9 10 11 12))
```

Also,

1. If you know `*h*` and the indices each symbol maps to at macroexpansion time, the above works.
2. If you know `*h*` at macroexpansion but the indices each symbol maps to will change after macroexpansion, you will want to collect `(,key (aref *v-of-v* (gethash ,key *h*)))`.

PS: If you find `loop` ugly for hash-tables, you could use the `iterate` library with the syntax:

```lisp
(iter (for (key value) in-hashtable *h*)
  (collect `(,key (aref *v-of-v* ,value))))
```

Comment: I know the mappings as a data structure comes in. When I wrote that I don't know, I don't know if the keys will be 'a' 'b' and 'c', or something else, or what their index into the vectors will be. The goal is to eventually write: (map-it my-data-structure), where I'll pick out the hash table and vector-of-vectors and generate the symbol macros. maphash seemed the cleanest solution, but loops also work.