# Good example of when to muffle warnings?

Tags: common-lisp

This question is somewhat related to an earlier one on [programmatically generating symbol macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157488/programmatically-generating-symbol-macros). I'm using that function in a convenience macro that throws undefined variable warnings. This macro and function:

```lisp
(defmacro define-data (d body &optional doc)
  (if (and doc (not (stringp doc))) (error "Documentation is not a string"))
  `(let* ((d-str (string ',d))
          (old-package *package*)
          (*package* (if (find-package d-str)    ;exists?
                         (find-package d-str)    ;yes, return it
                         (make-package d-str)))) ;no, make it
     ;; Should we have an eval-when (:compile-toplevel) here?
     (defparameter ,d ,body ,doc)
     (export ',d old-package)
     (define-column-names ,d)))

(defun define-column-names (d)
  (maphash #'(lambda (key index)
           (eval `(cl:define-symbol-macro ,key (cl:aref (columns ,d) ,index))))
       (ordered-keys-table (slot-value d 'ordered-keys))))
```

are intended to be like `defparameter`, but additionally set up a few niceties for the user by defining:

1. a package with the name of `d`
2. a parameter in the current package with the data that will be sucked in by `body`
3. symbol-macros in package `d` for access to the individual data vectors

If I use `defparameter` from the REPL, and then call `define-column-names`, all is well. However when using the macro I get:

```
; in: DEFINE-COLUMN-NAMES FOO
;     (DEFINE-COLUMN-NAMES CL-USER::FOO)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: CL-USER::FOO
```

I suspect that this is because the compiler has no way of knowing that FOO will actually be defined when `define-symbol-macro` is called. Everything works fine, but I don't want the warning to frighten users, so am thinking of suppressing it. I hate suppressing warnings though, so thought I'd come here for a second opinion.

EDIT: I've marked an answer correct because it does correctly answer the question as asked. For an answer to the problem see my comments.

Comment: Okay, it's ugly, and I'm not exactly sure why, but using *another* eval seems to 'fix' the problem: (eval '(define-column-names ,df)). I can understand why one is needed in define-column-names based on @rainer-joshwig explanation on the earlier question, but this one I don't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer to the 'when to muffle warnings' question in the title is: *if it's your own code then never, under any circumstances*.  If it is someone else's code, then rewrite it not to warn unless you can't.

As to solving the problem I haven't thought about this hard enough, but the problem is that you definitely want the `defparameter` to be at top-level so the compiler can see it, and it can't really be if it's inside a `let`.  But you can raise it to toplevel trivially since it depends on nothing inside the `let`.

I am then pretty certain that you want the rest of the macro to happen at compile time, because you definitely want the symbol-macros available at compile-time.  So an attempt at the first macro would be (note I've fixed the handling of the docstring: `(defparameter foo 1 nil)` is bad):

```
(defmacro define-data (d body &optional doc)
  (when (and doc (not (stringp doc)))
    (error "Documentation is not a string"))
  `(progn
     (defparameter ,d ,body ,@(if doc (list doc) '()))
     (eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
       (let* ((d-str (string ',d))
              (old-package *package*)
              (*package* (if (find-package d-str)    ;exists?
                             (find-package d-str)    ;yes, return it
                           (make-package d-str)))) ;no, make it
         (export ',d old-package)
         (define-column-names ,d)))))
```

As a side note: although I think the fact that programmatically defining symbol macros is hard because CL left that out for some reason, I think I'd personally use some other approach rather than this, because `eval` is just so horrid.  That's just me however: if you want to do this you do need `eval` I think (it is very rare that this is true!).

Comment: I tried moving everything possible outside the let before I wrote this message, but it doesn't work. In that case, define-column-names doesn't work at all. I went a bit down the path suggested by @coredump, moving the define-symbol-macro into the define-data macro, but didn't get too far. I think that's probably something to look at again. What I wonder is *why* define-column-names only works when defparameter is within the same lexical scope (i.e. within the let)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly how `define-columns-names` works so I replaced it with a stub function that returns `d`.

Note also that you can use `check-type` and should try not injecting symbols in generated code, this introduces potential variable capture that can be avoided with `gensym`.

As far as I know you cannot use `eval-when` as suggested by your comment (see [*Issue EVAL-WHEN-NON-TOP-LEVEL Writeup*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Issues/iss147_w.htm) for details).

But I have no warning if I declare the symbol as being special around the call.

```
(defmacro define-data (d body &optional doc)
  (check-type doc (or null string))
  (check-type d symbol)
  (let ((d-str (string d)))
    (alexandria:with-gensyms (old-package)
      `(let* ((,old-package *package*)
              (*package* (if (find-package ,d-str)    ;exists?
                             (find-package ,d-str)    ;yes, return it
                             (make-package ,d-str)))) ;no, make it
         (defparameter ,d ,body ,doc)
         (export ',d ,old-package)
         (locally (declare (special ,d))
           (define-column-names ,d))))))
```

It is also a bit strange that you expand into a call to `define-column-names`, which in turns evaluated a form built at runtime. I think it might be possible to do all you want during macroexpansion time, but as said earlier what you are trying to do is a bit unclear to me. What I have in mind is to replace `define-column-names` by:

```
,@(expand-column-names-macros d)
```

... where `expand-column-names-macros` builds a list of `define-symbol-macro` forms.

Comment: Yes, you're right that `(let ... (eval-when ...))` is meaningless: that's just not at toplevel and you can't make it be so.