# Equivalent of getters/accessors in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, getter, accessor, clisp

I am writing a program where each time I access the value of a boolean, no matter how it's accesed, it's value inverts (even if just printing it). In an OOP language the way I would accomplish this would by defining an accessor/getter function for this method. How can I accomplish this in common lisp.

Here is some example code I have written using lisp macros which outputs the expected values, but requires all references to be wrapped like this `(A)`. It would also require me to define a new macro for each boolean. If possible I would like to avoid these two issues.

```lisp
#!/bin/clisp

(defun getval(x)
  (set x (not (eval x)))
  (return-from getval (eval x)))

(setq a_private 'nil)
(defmacro A() (getval 'a_private))

(format t "A -> ~d~%" (A))
(format t "A -> ~d~%" (A))
(format t "A -> ~d~%" (A))
(format t "A -> ~d~%" (A))

; this returns the following:
; A -> T
; A -> NIL
; A -> T
; A -> NIL
```

Comment: Use `symbol-value`, not `eval`

Comment: You can use `define-symbol-macro` to avoid having to use parentheses. But there isn't really a way to avoid having to define a new one for each variable.

Comment: Yes thank you `define-symbol-macro` is exactly what I was looking for. I have also changed `eval` to `symbol-value` as per your suggetion. With this info combined with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157488/programmatically-generating-symbol-macros I should be able to figure out the answer.

Comment: why write a macro and not a function?

Comment: I'm fairly new to lisp so I don't have a particularly good reason for using a macro. This was mostly just some example code to illustrate the desired behaviour. I would like it to behave in that way but also be able to use a syntax like `(and a b)` because I need to reference the bools frequently. Perhaps a function is a better solution than a symbol macro.

Comment: The macro you wrote makes little sense and not in the way you wrote it. Macros generate code. Your macro does not generate code. A function then is sufficient.

Comment: Maybe you should show how you'd do this in an »OOP« language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to have some variables which toggle from `TRUE` to `FALSE`. From the code snippet above I don't really understand what is going on, so I will make the proposals below, I do hope you will find the one which suits you well.

1. Keep it simple and use simple `boolean` values

```
(defparameter var1 nil)
(defparameter var2 nil)

(format t "== SIMPLE WAY == ~%")
(format t "STEP 1~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" var1)
(format t "B -> ~A~%" var2)

(setf var1 (not var1))
(setf var2 (not var2))

(format t "STEP 2~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" var1)
(format t "B -> ~A~%" var2)

(setf var1 (not var1))
(setf var2 (not var2))

(format t "STEP 3~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" var1)
(format t "B -> ~A~%" var2)
```

2. You want to go further and dive into the world of `structures`

```
(format t "== STRUCT AND FUNCTIONS == ~%")

(defstruct status
    (flag nil))

;; function to toggle the 'flag' from structure of type 'status'
;; Returns the new status
(defun toggle-flag (status-object)
  (let ((previous-flag (status-flag status-object))) ;; get the current flag
    (let ((new-flag (not previous-flag)))            ;; calculate the new flag
      (setf (status-flag status-object) new-flag)    ;; update the new flag
      ;; return value
      new-flag)))
    
(defparameter var1 (make-status)) ;; create a new object status
(defparameter var2 (make-status)) ;; create a new object status

(format t "STEP 1~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" (status-flag var1))
(format t "B -> ~A~%" (status-flag var2))

(format t "STEP 2~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" (toggle-flag var1))
(format t "B -> ~A~%" (toggle-flag var2))

(format t "STEP 3~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" (toggle-flag var1))
(format t "B -> ~A~%" (toggle-flag var2))
```

3. You likes OOP adventures and you want to use `classes` and `methods`

```
(format t "== CLASSES == ~%")

(defclass state ()           ;; define a new class 'state'
   ((flag                    ;; with a field 'flag'
       :accessor state-flag  ;; accessible with the function (state-flag)
       :initform nil)))      ;; initialized with nil

;; Method to toggle the 'flag' from object of type 'state'
;; Will return the new status
(defmethod toggle ((object state))
  (let ((previous-status (state-flag object)))
    (let ((new-status (not previous-status)))
      (setf (state-flag object) new-status)
      ;; return value
      new-status)))

(defparameter var1 (make-instance 'state)) ;; create a new object state
(defparameter var2 (make-instance 'state)) ;; create a new object state
 
(format t "STEP 1~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" (state-flag var1))
(format t "B -> ~A~%" (state-flag var2))

(format t "STEP 2~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" (toggle var1))
(format t "B -> ~A~%" (toggle var2))

(format t "STEP 3~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" (toggle var1))
(format t "B -> ~A~%" (toggle var2))
```

All these examples should give you the expected result:

```
STEP 1
A -> NIL
B -> NIL
STEP 2
A -> T
B -> T
STEP 3
A -> NIL
B -> NIL
```

4. The last option I could provide would be to use amazing `closures`:

```
(defun make-toggler ()
  (let ((flag nil)) ;; create a new variable (available only to the closure)
    (lambda ()      ;; return a function... which toggle the variable!
      (setf flag (not flag))
      ;; return value
      flag)))

(defparameter var1 (make-toggler))
(defparameter var2 (make-toggler))

(format t "STEP 1~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" (funcall var1))
(format t "B -> ~A~%" (funcall var2))

(format t "STEP 2~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" (funcall var1))
(format t "B -> ~A~%" (funcall var2))

(format t "STEP 3~%")
(format t "A -> ~A~%" (funcall var1))
(format t "B -> ~A~%" (funcall var2))
```